# What language are the mother and boys speaking in "Life of Pi" when talking about Hindu gods? Looking for dialog

Tags: dialogue, translation, subtitles

I'm working on perfecting the subtitling in my current favorite movie, "Life of Pi." I would like to include the languages as spoken by the characters, along with the translations. I have the Tamil for "Pi's Lullaby" and the French that the cook speaks can be found in subtitle files in French, but I'm not finding native-language renderings of the interaction between the mother and her two sons beginning just before 13 minutes into the film. Any help locating a transcript would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 4):

It's Tamil. In that scene, she was telling a myth story to her young sons. (In that story, Yashoda is Krishna's foster mother, Krishna is an infant boy). I don't know if you want the script in native Tamil or in English.

00:12:58,236 --> 00:13:00,238
Yashoda once accused
baby Krishna of eating dirt.

00:13:01,030 --> 00:13:05,080
"Tut, tut you naughty boy -
you shouldn't do that."

00:13:05,493 --> 00:13:08,292
But he didn't!

00:13:09,372 --> 00:13:10,840
That's what he told her.

00:13:10,957 --> 00:13:12,925
"I didn't eat dirt."

00:13:13,626 --> 00:13:16,721
Yashoda said,
"No? Well then..."

00:13:16,921 --> 00:13:19,049
"Open your mouth."

00:13:19,215 --> 00:13:21,968
So Krishna opened his mouth.

00:13:22,135 --> 00:13:24,137
And what do you think
Yashoda saw?

00:13:24,220 --> 00:13:25,437
What?

00:13:26,222 --> 00:13:33,822
She saw in Krishna's mouth
the whole entire universe.